# Why does Rust closure not follow the lifetime elision rule?

Tags: rust

Let's consider a closure that immediately returns the reference it gets from the argument.

```rust
fn main() {
    let closure = |x: &i32| x;
    println!("{}", closure(&42));
}
```

It doesn't work because the Rust compiler believes that the returning reference has no correlation with the argument reference.

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:29
  |
2 |     let closure = |x: &i32| x;
  |                       -   - ^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |                       |   |
  |                       |   return type of closure is &'2 i32
  |                       let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

If we explicitly teach the compiler by manually annotating the type of the closure, it will work.

```rust
fn main() {
    let closure: for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> &'a i32 = |x: &i32| x;
    println!("{}", closure(&42));
}
```

However, the [lifetime elision rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision) states the following:

> If there is exactly one input lifetime position (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

In which case the compiler should have concluded that `'1` and `'2` in the error message to be the same.

Is there a reason that the lifetime elision rule is not applicable to closure type inference?

**Update:**

An answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843906) confirms that the lifetime elision rule does not apply to the closure. But the question is *why* it does not apply.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56537

Comment: I believe the discussion for this takes place in the github issue linked in my comment above

Comment: "Why" as in "why was the language designed so"? If yes, it is opinion-based.